# elasticdump : dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: conn ect ECONNREFUSED MY_IP:PORT

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

When i used localhost as IP-address it worked as expected

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>elasticdump --input=http://localhost:9200/wellnessservices --out
put=http://192.168.2.87:9200/wellnessservices --type=mapping
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset:
 0)
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination elasticsearch, wro
te 1
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset:
 1)
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | Total Writes: 1
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:56:47 GMT | dump complete
```

But when i specify the IP-address for the same localhost then i am getting error as shown below

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>elasticdump --input=http://192.168.2.83:9200/wellnessservices --
output=http://192.168.2.87:9200/wellnessservices --type=mapping
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 10:02:51 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 10:02:52 GMT | Error Emitted => connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.2.
83:9200
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 10:02:52 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 10 Jan 2017 10:02:52 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: conn
ect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.2.83:9200
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. It shouldn't be the problem with socket, because I added --maxSockets=5 in the command.

```
Fri, 20 Jan 2017 20:32:53 GMT | Error Emitted => connect ECONNREFUSED <IP>
Fri, 20 Jan 2017 20:32:53 GMT | Total Writes: 166700
Fri, 20 Jan 2017 20:32:53 GMT | dump ended with error (set phase)  => Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <IP>
```